# "after abusing it for three years" vs "after having abused it for three years"

Tags: grammar

I was writing a blog post about my phone this morning, and this is how I started it:

> Last week, after abusing it for over three years, I retired my
>   trusty old HTC Desire and replaced it with an HTC One.

This sentence didn't feel quite right to me, so I changed it to:

> Last week, after having abused it for over three years, I retired my
>   trusty old HTC Desire and replaced it with an HTC One.

But this doesn't feel quite right to me, either. What am I doing wrong? Which one of these sentence is correct? Why?

Comment: Also, the antecedent to "it" in both clauses is unclear because it seems to refer to I and not your HTC Desire.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is not very much difference in meaning between those two sentences.

Use of the [past participle](http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/grammar/learnit/learnitv305.shtml) form (having abused) emphasizes that the first action has been completed before the second action begins.

However, the use of *after* makes it seem a little bit redundant. Perhaps it might sound better without *after*.

> Having abused it for over three years, I retired my trusty old HTC Desire and replaced it last week with an HTC One.

It's really just about style: what you want to say, and how formally you want to say it.